# Intellij - Open directory of selected file in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, I could use Easy Shell and have a command to open the directory of the selected file in Cygwin.

I wonder if it is possible for Intellij.

The best I could do so far is use Terminal plugin and open the "root directory" of the module, not the directory of the selected file.

If there is a way to add a new context menu item like "Show in Cygwin" similar to "Show in Explorer", that will be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that with **Settings**——**Tools**——**External Tools**——**Add**:

Program: `your\path\to\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe`
Parameters: `/bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash --login`
Working Directory: `$FileDir$`

Note to uncheck **Open Console**, and it's done.

Reference: [ConEmu | Cygwin Startup Directory](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartDir.html) and IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.0 Help :: External Tools

Jesus, I can't post images and more than 2 links due to my low reputation, eww.

---

My tip for people who don't know how to run cygwin bash.exe *nicely* from **Terminal**:

- Create file `start-bash.bat` with following code inside:

  ```
  @echo off
  set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
  ```
- Copy file path to **Settings**——**Terminal**——**Shell path**

Only in this way can you start `bash.exe` from project directory instead of `$HOME`. Since **Shell path** is hard-coded and too difficult to get hacked, I don't know how to specify a subdirectory, whatever.

Comment: Thanks Joshz.  I use back Eclipse these days because Intellij  gives me some weird maven error for my project.  I will take a note of it and try it when I use Intellij again in future.  Thank you for the tip!